# What's the difference between listing nameservers in /etc/resolv.conf and /etc/network/interfaces in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, virtual-machines

I am deploying Ubuntu 12.04 VM's from a template using vCenter 5.5. When I try to add nameservers using a customization specification they are added to the resolv.conf file. The VM will not use these nameservers, and will be unable to resolve names. I can, however, manually specify the same nameservers using the dig command and successfully resolve names. If I manually add nameservers to /etc/network/interfaces the VM will use them and becomes able to resolve names. What is the cause of this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have `resolvconf` installed on your system it will manage `/etc/resolv.conf` for you.  Anything you manually put into `resolv.conf` will be replaced eventually, which is why name servers need to be defined in `/etc/network/interfaces` or the `interfaces.d` directory.

If you want to control `resolv.conf` manually remove the `resolvconf` package.

<sup>Note: It is typically best to configure and manage your system based on the best practices defined by your distribution or vendor.  If you remove `resolvconf` make sure you aren't breaking anything else that requires it.</sup>

Comment: Inside `/etc/network/interfaces`, if 2 interfaces have 2 different DNS servers, does an interface use both DNS servers when resolving a name, or just their respective DNS server that is set in the `/etc/network/interfaces` file?

Comment: Name servers wouldn't be assigned to specific interfaces.  If you specify different name servers in each `interface.d` script they'll just be assigned to the entire system (they will be configured in `resolv.conf`).